# Swift - how to avoid view move when focus on textfield (issue)

Tags: swift, storyboard

I have my Storyboard and I have 3 separate views with a root UINavigationController that will act as a wizard and that I show on top of my main application.

[image]

When I select a row then I push a second UIViewController:

[image]

The issues comes exactly when I focus the textfield, somehow my view moves to a left corner:

[image]

Is this an issue regarding some constrain that I have to add to my view? In case is that what constrains do I have to add?

This only happens when I focus the field.

Comment: what is going on in textfieldDidBeginEditing or do you have a notification for keyboard will show?

Comment: Hi I dont have any code that reference the textfield.

Comment: but the problem comes only when you begin editing in the textfield?  What constraints do you have on the view that contains the textfield?